# Puzzle to match up the shapes on inner edges

Tags: visual, puzzle-identification

My daughter (pre-school) had to solve the following puzzle:

[image: puzzle]

It consists of 9 square pieces and the goal is to fit them together in such a way that all inner (i.e. touching) sides show a valid, put-together pattern.

What is this type of puzzle called?

Is there a logical or even programmatical way (that is, not brute forcing it) to solve this type of puzzle?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably simply called an [edge-matching puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge-matching_puzzle) (also known by various names such as Tetravex). The puzzle is in general NP-complete (i.e. not easy to solve in general cases), but the algorithms for solving do exist (e.g., Douglas-Rachford algorithm, but unfortunately I don't know the details).

Comment: [Rob Stegmann's Puzzle Page](http://www.robspuzzlepage.com/pattern.htm) shows many of these puzzles, including many variations with 3x3 square tiles, and has a bit of history of such puzzles.